# Fazer um parser em um arquivo txt

Tags: java, text

Bom dia,

Criei um arquivo *.txt com determinados caminhos, agora preciso colocar esses caminhos dentro de variáveis para chamá-los na aplicação. Pensei em usar um **parser** para pegar essas informações, porém não consegui nenhum exemplo. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

> inPath = C:\Entrada --- Diretório de entrada
>   outPath = C:\Saida -- Diretório de saida
>   inProcess = C:\Em Processamento -- Diretório de processamento

Comment: O que você já fez? O que você quer fazer (insira mais detalhes do ``parser``)?

Comment: Eu tentei usar o método split, mas não consegui o que queria. Dai vi exemplos de parser para arquivos XML, porém para arquivos TXT não encontrei nenhum exemplo. Também não sei se é possível aplicar o metodo parser em um arquivo TXT

Comment: respondi lá fi!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por se tratar de um arquivo de configuração eu recomendaria você usar um arquivo do tipo `.ini`, mas infelizmente o Java não tem uma biblioteca padrão para fazer esse tipo de operação, se concordar em fazer assim pode baixar a biblioteca do endereço: http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/ Também existe a opção de baixá-la direto pelo Maven.

Baixada e importada a biblioteca, você precisa colocar uma seção no seu arquivo para que ele seja corretamente interpretado com um arquivo do tipo `.ini`. Exemplo:

> [cfg]
>   inPath=C:\Entrada              ; Diretório de entrada
>   outPath=C:\Saida               ; Diretório de saida
>   inProcess=C:\Em Processamento  ; Diretório de processamento

E o código ficaria assim:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ini4j.Ini;
import org.ini4j.IniPreferences;
import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
        Ini ini = new Ini(new File("meucfg.ini"));
        java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs = new IniPreferences(ini);        
        String inPath = prefs.node("cfg").get("inPath", "null").split(";")[0].trim();
        String outPath = prefs.node("cfg").get("outPath", "null").split(";")[0].trim();
        String inProcess = prefs.node("cfg").get("inProcess", "null").split(";")[0].trim();

        System.out.printf("inPath: %s\noutPath: %s\ninProcess: %s\n", inPath, outPath, inProcess);
    }    
}
```

Saída:

> inPath: C:\Entrada
>   outPath: C:\Saida
>   inProcess: C:\Em Processamento

Comment: eu não consegui criar um arquivo .ini

Comment: esse arquivo .ini eu consigo criar no notepad?

Comment: isso, só muda a extensao de txt para ini

Comment: perfeito, deu certinho agora

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não sei direito qual vai ser seu processamento no **parser**. Considerando que você pega linha por linha e processa, eu fiz essa solução, que ao processar a linha já salva no diretório de saída, sem usar o diretório `inProcess`, porque não sei se você realmente precisa.

```
String inPath = "C:\Entrada\dados.txt"
String outPath = "C:\Saida\dados.txt"
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(outPath);
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(inPath));
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = in.nextLine();
     // faz processamento com vários métodos para auxiliar
     // line.split(regex);
     // line.compareTo(anotherString);
     // line.contains(string);
     // line.matches(regex);
     // ... vários outros
     System.out.println(line);
     file.write(line_processed);   // salva linha já processada
}
file.close();
```

Obviamente que essa não é a única solução!